# Why is the date unparseable

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to parse a new Date object, but I keep hitting the following error.

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu May 16 09:28:39 GMT+01:00 2019"
```

I've attempted various different patterns for dateFormat, but nothing seems to work.

This is where the error is.

```
c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(oldDate));
```

Code

```
  public static String addDay(int numberOfDays) {

    String oldDate = String.valueOf(new Date());

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
     c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(oldDate));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,numberOfDays);
    dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss",  Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date newDate=new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    String resultDate=dateFormat.format(newDate);
    return resultDate;
}
```

Comment: Well, the date doesn't match the format at all, e.g. `dd-MM-yyyy` means something like `16-05-2019` which is _not_ `Thu May 16 ... 2019`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes. They're outdated, and [flawed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). Better use the new Java Date and Time API, from the `java.time` package, or else the ThreeTen ABP.

Comment: @Michael I'm sure they're rotating in their graves ;) - Seriously: `Date.toString()` uses the format  `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` (see the source code, the javadoc describes it in a little different terms that need "transformation").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This function

In your question you are converting `Date` to `string`

then after you are once again Parsing `String` to `Date`

that is very Long way. you can directly set as 
`c.setTime(oldDate);`

```
  public static String addDay(int numberOfDays) {
    Date oldDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(oldDate);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,numberOfDays);
    dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss",  Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date newDate=new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    String resultDate=dateFormat.format(newDate);
    return resultDate;
  }
```

Comment: ... and the Date object is not even needed

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what you changed. At first glance it is quite similar.

Comment: @ScaryWombat because  converting old date to string, then after convert into date . and parse . its very long way, try it old date in Date object directly directly

Comment: @Michael check it out edited answer , and i dont know why i downvotted.

Comment: If you read the javadocs you would read *Calendar provides a class method, getInstance, for getting a generally useful object of this type. Calendar's getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose calendar fields have been initialized with the current date and time:*, hence Date is not needed at all

Answer (score 0):

The pattern should be like :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                            Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then to print you need a second SimpleDateFormat:

```
Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(date);

SimpleDateFormat print = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss");

System.out.println(print.format(parsedDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is wrong. You should use `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`